# How to get the current URL of a page in a Django template?

Tags: python, django

I know there is another question with virtually the same title as mine but the solution in that one didn't work for me. My url is like this:

```
http://domain.com/videos/dvd/1/
```

If I use either `{{baseurl}}` or `{{ request.get_full_path }}` I get just this part:

```
http://domain.com/videos/
```

How can I get the entire url? I need to be able to do this from the template level.

### EDIT

P.S. it should disregard any parameters that may be in the url.

Answer (score 9):

You could get it in your view and pass it along into your template context so that it is available to you there.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri

```
full_url = request.build_absolute_uri(None)

# pass full_url into the template context.
```

Comment: Or use `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}` directly in the template.

Comment: @tutuca: Make sure your template is being rendered with a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) so that the `request` variable is available inside the template.

Comment: My proyect has the request context processor, and AFAIK the django_registration templates are rendered with a `RequestContext` by default